# How to get an int[] from a string of integers in javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to allow a user to be able to enter a list of IDs into a textarea and allow the IDs to be seperated by whitespace such as a new line as well as by commas.

Then I'd like to convert that into an int[] or throw an error if the string is bad: contains letters, decimals, etc.

But I'm having trouble working it out.

Can anyone give an example of how to do this?

I'd apprecuate any help.

Comment: Literally as you described. Read textarea value, split by separators, convert to int's, throw error if 'string is bad'. In what part were you 'having trouble'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the [`split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), you can pass it a regular expression to split by. For example:

```
var myArray=myString.split(/[^\d]+/);
```

This would return an array of strings, each containing a string representation of an integer. Furthermore, you can then use the [`parseInt` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseInt) to parse those string representations to integers, like so:

```
var myIntArray=[];
for(var i=0;i<myStringArray.length;i++) {
    myIntArray.push(parseInt(myStringArray[i], 10));
}
```

You can see a full example with some jQuery helpers (specifically, [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9wRXL/).

Comment: I didn't know of `\D`, and `[^\d]` worked just fine, so that's why I used it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function.

What you'll need to do is split the text in the textarea based on your desired delimiter, then iterate through the array to convert to integers.  Since the `split` function takes a single separator, you'll need to normalize the input a bit, say by converting line breaks to whitespace.